# iframe onload not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using an iframe to upload images, but the javascript function for the iframe isn't being called. Actually, if the name/id of the iframe is "upload", then the if(success) argument is called in the javascript function, but the if(fail) argument is not. If I change the name/id of the iframe to something else, either argument is called. Name/id shouldn't even impact the javascript? When I first built it, only the if(fail) argument was being called, and not the success one. I have no idea what's going on.

My form:

```
<form id="profileForm" method="post" action="build/parsers/upload-photo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="newphoto">
     <input type="hidden" name="kind" value="profile" />
     <input type="file" name="photo" id="profileSelect" onchange="uploadPhoto();" />
     <button id="profileUpload" onclick="document.getElementById('profileSelect').click(); return false;" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> <span>Upload Profile Picture</span></button>
</form>
```

The uploadPhoto() function:

```
function uploadPhoto() {
    $('#profileForm').submit();
    $('#photo').html("<div style='background: #dadada;'><img src='build/images/loading.gif' /></div>");
    }
```

The iframe:

```
<iframe name="newphoto" id="newphoto" onload="stopPhoto('<?php echo $username ?>');"></iframe>
```

And the stopPhoto(), which is the one **NOT WORKING**

```
function stopPhoto(user) {
    var iframe      = document.getElementById('newphoto');
    var innerDoc    = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var fail        = innerDoc.getElementById('fail');
    var success     = innerDoc.getElementById('success');
    var file        = success.innerHTML;
    var error       = fail.innerHTML;

    if(fail != null) {
        $('#photo').html("");
        $('#alert').css('display', 'block').html(error);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#alert').fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    }
    if(success != null) {
        $('#photo').html("<div style=\"background: url('users/"+user+"/profile/m/"+file+"') center no-repeat;\"></div>'");
    }

}
```

My PHP file will output one of two divs within the iframe:

```
<div id="success">name.jpg</div>
<div id="fail">Error message</div>
```

Whhhhhhhy isn't my stopPhoto() function working properly? Only bits and pieces of it are called, and the only thing I've noticed is that the name/id of the iframe determines what works and what doesn't. Please help!

Comment: I think you are using .click() on document.getElementById. .click() is a jquery function. So change that to .onclick()

Comment: I am using jquery. That part of the code works fine. Everything works except for stopPhoto().

Comment: @user2250471 Neither `<div id="success">name.jpg</div>` , 
`<div id="fail">Error message</div>` appended to `iframe` before `stopPhoto` called at `onload` `event` ?